# Solution to $x(128)x=(12365)(479)$ in $A_9$, the alternating group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

This isn't homework. I'm wondering if anyone knows techniques besides trial and error to find $x$ or show there is no solution, to problems like this, or worse, say $xpx^2rx^{-4}=s$, where $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ are given permutations in some $S_n$, $n$ given, and $x$ is an unknown permutation in $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ elements. I'm thinking that that could lead to more interesting things like functions, $y=f(x)=x(128)x(34)$, or nonfunctional "curves", like $x^2pxy^2qx^2=r$. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I guess the solution to the title problem could well be odd, in S9, not A9.

Comment: By using the fact that the right side fixes 8, and taking the nine possible values of $x(8),$ one can rule them all out one by one by considering what the left side does, and comparing to the right side. This would be considered "trial and error" so not worth an answer (if desired I could put up details). But I don't see a simple (non-detail) way to rule out a solution for the equation in the heading to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't fit these in the comments, not really an answer this one...

In general, this should be difficult. For instance, a special case of that would be the conjugacy problem for a group. That is, given $a$ and $b$, find $x$ such that $a=xbx^{-1}$.

Now, even the [Conjugacy Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_problem) is undecidable in many classes of groups. Of course, things are better for the symmetric group, and any braid group (see [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870898917613)), actually any garside group (see [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303002928)).

Now, for the general situation and arbitrary equations, there are geometric techniques that I don't know much about, but this [presentation](http://www.osti.gov/eprints/topicpages/documents/record/445/2278269.html) seems like a starting point. There is also a very nice [blog post](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/equations-over-groups-a-mess/).